# android ubuntu one sync changes back

Tags: sync, android, keepass

Can i sync changes from my Android to U1 and therefore back to my pc.

I am hoping to sync my keepass database between my pc and phone.  If I subscribe to a site through my phone, I'd like to have those changes back to my pc from my phone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the lead developer of Ubuntu One Files. And I also wish to use keepassx with it one day :)

Yes, more full-feature sync engine will come, I can't give any dates yet, though.